# No WPA2 option in Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wpa2-psk

I have a fresh Windows XP SP3 installation on several PCs but none of them has WPA/WPA2 option in Wireless Networks section of the connection properties regardless of wireless adapters they have (that supports WPA2). Can someone provide an advice on how to fix that?

Comment: I have Atheros 5212 based card with latest (v. 7.7) drivers.

Comment: According to this page, http://www.atheros.com/pt/AR5002G.htm, the card doesn't support wpa2.

Comment: WPA2 works fine with Atheros's Ekahau Wireless Utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest drivers installed for the wireless adapter.  I recently reinstalled Windows XP and all the service packs on a laptop, and it didn't see (and could not join) any WPA2 networks until I updated the WiFi drivers.

Comment: I've updated drivers but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

WinXP SP3 already contains the update adding WPA2 support to the operating system (refer to [List of fixes that are included in Windows XP Service Pack 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946480/), details can be found in "Description of the Wireless Client Update for Windows XP with Service Pack 2").

However you also need drivers supporting WPA2. For some old chipsets there are no drivers available supporting WPA2. If that's the case you are out of luck and have two alternative options available (depending on your circumstances):
a) Allow WPA in your WLAN (potentially reducing the security)
b) Get WPA2 compliant WLAN hardware

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and reinstalling network drivers (from the manufacturer's website, eg. broadcom or intel) allowed me to connect to my WPA2 network.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall SP3 and install the KB 893357 update from Microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP does not support WPA2 out of the box. You need to install [KB893357](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=662bb74d-e7c1-48d6-95ee-1459234f4483).

Comment: This is already included in SP3